# django nginx gunicorn application showing apache2 default page - only on ip request not domain name

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Very odd behavior from my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server

I have followed this tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) (twice) and it is all working properly except a couple odd things

firstly, when I use my browser to visit the IP of my VPS, the django default application page shows up throughout the tutorial however accessing it through the domain name results in a time out error

secondly, now that I have completed the tutorial and configured nginx to proxy pass to gunicorn, the apache2 ubuntu default page is now displaying instead of the django default page on a visit to the ip address and still no response from the domain name, even though there is no installation of apache2 on this server...

```
$ whereis apache2
apache2:
```

here is my `gunicorn.socket` file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

here is my `gunicorn.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=trends
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/trends_dir
ExecStart=/trends_dir/trendsvenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          trends.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available` config file for the site, which has been properly symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.trendsontheblock.com trendsontheblock.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /trends_dir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

like i said, no errors from the ip address and cannot get a response from the domain name, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Are you sure that domain mapped probably to the IP?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby `ping`ing it has lead me to see it is not the correct ip, but why then am i `ssh`ing to that ip, and the browser is reacting to changes made on the server from that ip i have been using to test it?

Comment: Because you are using IP, so it is fine, the problem is domain-ip mapping.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby thank you, i will contact my hosting service's support team and find a resolution

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby okay so i have updated my track A record to be inline with the new ip address, there was an issue due to me having switched from shared hosting to vps recently, however visiting my site by domain name results in no response still and there is still the issue of the apache2 default page when visiting the ip address, when there is no apache2 on the vps

Comment: The ip may take 24 hours till it is updated to new IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Mohamed in the comments section the error was due to incorrect ip-domain mapping caused by an inconsistent A record value in my domain name hosting service (godaddy)

This was because I had switched from shared hosting to VPS and the domain name's name-server values had therefore become inconsistent

The domain-name server needed to be reset to the default host values and it's A record was updated to the new VPS server's IP this has solved my issue